# Alterar texto de outro formulário não funciona

Tags: c#, winforms

Segue código:

Form2:

```
public void ChangeLabel(string s)
{
    labelX1.Text = s;
}
```

E dentro Form1:

```
private void button_MostrarSegundaTela_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Screen.AllScreens.Length > 1)
    {
        //Estendido
        SegundaTela formulario = new SegundaTela();
        Screen[] telas = Screen.AllScreens;
        Rectangle bounds = telas[1].Bounds; // pode ser outro índice.
        formulario.SetBounds(bounds.X, bounds.Y, bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
        formulario.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        formulario.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        //Duplicado, ou apenas 1 tela
        MessageBox.Show("Estender");
    }
}

private void label3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var result = label3.Text;

    SegundaTela frm2 = new SegundaTela();
    frm2.ChangeLabel(result);
}
```

A idéia é: Quando mudar `label` do form1, também mudar `label` do form2.

Não funciona. Aparentemente nada.

Alguma solução ?

Comment: Já verificou se a propriedade Modifiers está igual a public? Em modo private não vai deixar alterar de fora da classe.

Comment: Sim, já verifiquei na propriedade e está como Modifiers:`Public`.

Comment: Você está instanciando um form e mudando o valor do label, ok até aqui. Mas onde está a parte que form é mostrado????

Comment: @LINQ editei post. Ficou melhor.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda perceba que não faz sentido. Você instancia e mostra um form no primeiro if, no método citado *é criada uma nova instância do form* que nem sequer é mostrada

Comment: Sim, fiz isso para deixa a tela preta. Quando `label` for novo, mostrar...

Comment: Independente do motivo, não faz sentido criar uma instância nova. Mova a variável para um escopo mais abrangente.

Comment: Verdade, faz sentido.

Comment: Eu não tenho 2 monitores mas funcionou certinho quando fiz o teste alterando `Screen.AllScreens.Length > 0` e `Rectangle bounds = telas[0].Bounds`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No código que você tenta mudar o valor do label está sendo criada **uma nova instância** do form.

Ou seja, a instância que está sendo mostrada está intacta.

Mova a variável do form para um escopo mais abrangente e use esta variável para chamar o método que troca o valor do label.

Algo assim:

```
public class SuaTela
{
    SegundaTela telaSecundaria;

    private void button_MostrarSegundaTela_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Screen.AllScreens.Length > 1)
        {
            telaSecundaria = new SegundaTela();
            // resto do código 
            telaSecundaria.Show();
        }
    }

    private void label3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var result = label3.Text;
        telaSecundaria?.ChangeLabel(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: A linha: `Form telaSecundaria;` não seria `SegundaTela telaSecundaria` ? Porque ChangeLabel não reconhece.

Comment: Não precisa pq SegundaTela herda de Form

Comment: @MatheusMiranda desculpa aí, engano meu. Precisa sim